# Make the Winter Bash dropdown consistent with the others on the top bar

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2020

The winter bash dropdown isn't dark mode compatible.

1. The text is too dark. In fact, it [fails all WCAG standards](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=888888&bcolor=2D2D2D).

   [image]

   while text in the inbox looks like this:

   [image]
2. The scrollbar is not the same as in other dropdowns:

   [image]

   compared to:

   [image]

Comment: And in light mode, the text is too light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do have some tech debt in this area, and would look into fully converting the dropdown to use our [UI framework](https://stackoverflow.design/) in the future (which should make the look consistent with the rest of the site, and fix the dark-mode issues).

Unfortunately, I’m not going to have enough time to make these changes during this Winter Bash cycle.

> poor snowflake dropdown
> needs a refresh, UI love
> there’s always next time